# Should I always expect to receive proceedings at conferences?

Tags: conference, proceedings

I attended a conference in computer science recently, where we were not given any proceedings at the registration desk.
They said the papers are available online on the website of the conference inside the program detail.

However I know that the publisher (ACM) is not open access, and for example I have to buy the papers from the last conference if I like to read them.

So, there is a chance that the papers might be removed from the conference website 1-2 months after the conference.

I was wondering if giving proceedings to the attendees is a tradition only to make sure they have access to the contents during the conference?

Comment: Just to clarify: The papers are on the conference website, right? Your concern is simply that they may go offline in the future, right? Could you download them and save them?

Comment: @Thomas: It is feasible, but I have to go to all sessions one by one and download the papers individually. But above all I was wondering if we should expect to receive proceedings or not?

Comment: Putting up a website is a way of making the proceedings available to you. There are tools that allow you to download all contents from a website at once (like HTTrack), but you can also ask the publication chair(s) if they can make available a download for the whole thing.

Comment: No, you shouldn't expect to receive three pounds of printed paper any more in 2019. That world is one of the past.

Answer (score 2):

No, obviously you shouldn't expect to always get printed proceedings. Your recent experience proves it.

Yes, giving out proceedings to participants is a tradition to make sure they have access to the papers during the conferences. Nowadays, everyone attending a scientific conference has access to the internet, and everyone as a whole is becoming aware that wasting resources (paper, electricity to run the printer, etc) is harmful to the environment. (Of course, it doesn't prevent attendees from flying around the world to attend the conference, but "one step at a time I guess".) They have put the proceedings online, so you have access to them.

And honestly, if downloading the papers one at a time is such a hassle, maybe it's a sign that you weren't even going to read them all anyway. Finding one paper is a stack of dozens is also a hassle! And if we are not talking about dozens of papers, then the argument that downloading them one at a time is annoying does not really hold much water. You can report this minor inconvenience to the conference organizers, but be prepared to the fact that it will be dealt with like all other minor inconveniences.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a new practice of ACM and it may be limited to some conferences. Things may have changed (a lot) since my retirement. But, printing on paper is expensive, and costs are affected by decisions about printed proceedings.

But it is unlikely that anything will soon disappear as the proceedings, such as they are, will become part of the ACM Digital Library. They have also captured much of what was written in the past, making research in CS much easier.

You can subscribe to this yourself, for about $100 per year (last time I looked), and many members of ACM do subscribe. I did for a number of years.

However, it is highly likely that your university library has a subscription and that you can get a copy of just about anything by asking the librarian. In fact, it will probably have subscriptions to lots (lots) of such professional libraries. The rules may preclude you from asking for every paper in a proceedings, but will probably permit you to get a pdf of any single paper (or a few).

The world is changing. We may have crossed the boundary where most prefer electronic to paper copies. If this is the case, then the (expensive) printing becomes a waste of resources. I suspect that it will soon become the case if it isn't already.